# what's the $\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}$ of this?

Tags: partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2)$$
I just need the final answer, I have done it and I want to make sure that if I did it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: For this and future similar problems, you can use [symbolic differentiation online](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpartial%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B%5Cpartial%20x%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cleft(log%5Cleft(x%5E%7B2%7D%2B%20y%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5Cright))

Comment: thanks..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}=\frac{2y^2-2x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

> $2\frac{(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

The final answer should be $\frac{2(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$.

Comment: There should be square of  denominator..as per the quotient  rule of differentiation

Comment: @auscrypt, the denominator should have $(x^2+y^2)^2$, (I didn't downvote)